# Aligning decimal points in longtable environment

Tags: longtable, siunitx, dcolumn

I have a table created with longtable and I'd like to align the decimal points of the numbers in the table. I saw that previous posts suggested to use dcolumn or siunitx. However, I'm not able to make them work in my case.
Below I report the code as it was before trying to use dcolumn or siunitx, I hope it's clear enough:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\captionsetup{justification=centering, margin=0.7cm}

\geometry {a4paper, left = 25mm, right = 25mm, top = 38 mm, bottom = 38mm}

\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{ ``#1''}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\linespread{1.5}
      
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[l]{llcS[table-format=4.2]SSS} 

\caption{main} \\ \hline

 & (1) \\

VARIABLES & eu\_salience\_mean \\ \hline

 &  \\

1988.year & 0.289** \\

 & (0.106) \\

1992.year & 0.633*** \\

 & (0.185) \\

1996.year & 0.860*** \\

 & (0.205) \\

1999.year & 0.343 \\

 & (0.289) \\

2002.year & 2.011*** \\

 & (0.254) \\

2006.year & 0.966*** \\

 & (0.293) \\

2010.year & 1.469*** \\

 & (0.377) \\

2014.year & 0.992** \\

 & (0.344) \\

2017.year & 1.440*** \\

 & (0.425) \\

2019.year & 1.158** \\

 & (0.412) \\

Constant & 4.719*** \\

 & (0.225) \\

 &  \\

Observations & 138 \\

Number of country\_num & 14 \\

 R-squared & 0.432 \\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\

\multicolumn{2}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\

\label{tab:main}%

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

It's not that I get an error, it simply doesn't change the alignment of the numbers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unrelated but please make your example minimal by removing irrelevant packages. Note that `12 pt` should probably be without the spaces. I'd also recomment having a look at the `csquotes` package. Additionally using verdana does not seem to be relevant to this either.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's one of my first posts, next time I'll be more careful

Comment: don't leave `\label` on a row on its own in the table, it will make a blank row, put it in the caption. Other than that  you have used c column for your decimals. If you got an error using D or S show that (and you only need a one or two line example table) and without using non standard fonts

Comment: Sorry again. I edited the post above, I hope it's better now

Answer (score 1):

The core issue here is that you've got

```latex
\begin{longtable}[l]{llcS[table-format=4.2]SSS}
```

which means that the `S`-column is the fourth one, but your decimals are all in column two. Cutting down to a minimum to show the effect, I would use something like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    input-digits = ()01234567890,
    input-open-uncertainty = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-post = false
  }
  \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=2.4{***}] @{}} 
    \toprule
    Variable & {Mean} \\
    \midrule
    1988.year & 0.289** \\
              & (0.106) \\
    1992.year & 0.633*** \\
              & (0.185) \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

where I've made `()` into 'digits' so they work for alignment.

If you want to keep your non-statistical values in the able (rather than in a note), I would avoid aligning them:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{
    input-digits = ()01234567890,
    input-open-uncertainty = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-post = false
  }
  \begin{tabular}{@{} lS[table-format=2.4{***}] @{}} 
    \toprule
    Variable & {Mean} \\
    \midrule
    1988.year & 0.289** \\
              & (0.106) \\
    1992.year & 0.633*** \\
              & (0.185) \\
    \midrule
    Observations           & {138}   \\
    Number of country\_num & {14}    \\
    R-squared & {0.432} \\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```